# What is a good way to merge non intersecting sets in a list to end up with denseley packed sets?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm currently doing this by using a sort of a greedy algorithm by iterating over the sets from largest to smallest set. What would be a good algorithm to choose if i'm more concerned about finding the best solution rather than efficiency?

Details:
1) Each set has a predefined range
2) My goal is to end up with a lot of densely packed sets rather than reducing the total number of sets.

**Example:** Suppose the range is `8`.

The sets might be: `[1,5,7]`, `[2,6]`, `[3,4,5]`, `[1,2]` , `[4]`, `[1]`
A good result would be `[1,5,7,2,6,4]`, `[3,4,5,1,2]`, `[1]`

Comment: i don't understand the question.

Comment: Rather than sets, are you referring to interval?

Comment: Please add your current solution / example

Comment: I have a list of sets, each of which has values in a range. I can only merge 2 sets if they have no intersecting values. I am trying to maximize the number of densely packed/full sets.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: You want to maximize number of sets or minimize? If you want to maximize then put each unique element in a new set.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You want to maximize the sets themselves, which means you want the resulting sets to be as large as possible?

Comment: If you think of the sets as nodes in a graph, and the edges represent whether two sets are "compatible" (no element in common), it reduces to the [Clique problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), which is NP-complete.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot: so? You can reduce any problem in P to an NP-complete one; it's the reduction *in the other direction* that proves a problem NP-hard.

Comment: Construct sets such that, whenever two nodes does *not* have an edge, you add the same number to both sets, making them incompatible.

Comment: The question wasn't the complexity but how to do it.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot that will allow me to reduce the total number of sets but won't help me make the sets as dense as possible..

Comment: @HansThen, that is correct. Ideally, want as many sets as possible which contain the entire range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very complex question.  It could well be that using more complex graph algorithms this can be solved in a more efficient way than what I came up with, but here is what I've got.  It will be pretty slow to produce *all* solutions, but since it is a generator, maybe choosing a solution from the first *n* could be an option, depending on your concrete situation.

It does not solve the question which solution is the best, it just generates all possible solutions.  Also, you did not specify clearly enough what the "best" dense packing is.  In your original example (without the `[4]`), is solution `12567-12345-1` better than `123456-157-12`?  If so, why?  Speaking of lengths, solution 1 would be (5, 5, 1) while solution 2 would be (6, 2, 3).  Which is better?

```
input = map(set, [ [1,5,7], [2,6], [3,4,5], [1,2], [4], [1] ])

def eachCombination(input):
  if input:
    for combination, rest in eachCombination(input[1:]):
      yield combination, input[0:1] + rest
      if not (input[0] & combination):  # fits?
        yield input[0] | combination, rest
  else:
    yield set(), []

def eachPacked(input):
  for combination, rest in eachCombination(input):
    for restPart in rest:
      if not (combination & restPart):  # not densely packed?
        break
    else:
      yield combination, rest

def eachSolution(input):
  for packed, rest in eachPacked(input):
    if rest:
      for subsolution in eachSolution(rest):
        yield [ packed ] + subsolution
    else:
      yield [ packed ]

for solution in eachSolution(input):
  print '   '.join('-'.join('%d' % n for n in set) for set in solution)
```

This will print

```
1-2-3-4-5   1-2-4-5-6-7   1
1-2-3-4-5   1-2-4-6   1-5-7
1-2-4-5-6-7   1-2-3-4-5   1
1-2-4-5-6-7   1-3-4-5   1-2
1-2-4   1-2-5-6-7   1-3-4-5
1-2-4   1-2-3-4-5-6   1-5-7
1-2-3-4-5-6   1-4-5-7   1-2
1-2-3-4-5-6   1-2-4   1-5-7
1-2-4-6   1-5-7   1-2-3-4-5
1-2-4-6   1-2-3-4-5   1-5-7
```

Comment: Honestly, I have not yet codified what the 'best' density for my situation is. I will just create a density function to quantify it for a set and then use that function as the basis for the merging, so that I can refine the density function in time..

Comment: Since your task seems to be extremely complex it might be pragmatic to choose one possible solution from a random set of solutions.  I've got a modified version of my answer now which produces random solutions to choose from (just taking the first 1000 solutions from the program printed here probably does not make sense since the first 1000 solutions are all very much alike in large parts).  To prevent spamming here I put it to http://pastebin.com/rpENkiHw

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approximation, using dynamic programming:

http://ideone.com/SI1wEs

```
from operator import itemgetter

def find_maximum_set(sets):
    results = []
    for si,s in enumerate(sets):
        sn = len(s)
        new_set = set(s) # if nothing else works, add the set by itself
        new_len = sn
        new_is = [si]

        # try to combine it with all the previous results, picking the one that
        # would produce the largest union
        for rn,ris,r in results:
            if r.isdisjoint(s):
                rs = r.union(s)
                if rn+sn > new_len:
                    new_set = rs
                    new_len = rn+sn
                    new_is = ris + [si]

        # add the new set to the result collection
        results.append((new_len,new_is,new_set))

    # return the largest result
    return max(results, key=itemgetter(0))

def find_all_maximum_sets(sets):
    sets = list(sets)
    result = []
    while len(sets) > 0:
        _, indexes, largest = find_maximum_set(sets)
        result.append(largest)
        sets = [s for i,s in enumerate(sets) if i not in indexes]
    return result
```

**Example:**

```
>>> find_all_maximum_sets([[1,5,7], [2,6], [3,4,5], [1,2] , [4], [1]])
[set([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]), set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), set([1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it will give an optimal solution, but would simply repeatedly merging the two largest non-overlapping sets not work?

Comment: This is what i am currently doing. It will not give the optimal solution.